# Ajax request success handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a json implemented page where I am displaying a list of videos. I am getting the video `<embed>` codes as a javascript. While in the loop of creating the list, I use the `$.ajax` jquery function to initialize the javascript to get teh video flash player. but the problem is that the player is not getting appended to the supposed `<div>`. Instead it gets appended at teh end of the document.

```
$.ajax({
                url: item.ImagePath,
                dataType: "script",
                success: function(data){
                    alert(data);
                    var sResultFigure = $(document.createElement('figure')).append(result);
                }
            })
```

how do i solve this thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are looping over divs and triggering an AJAX request for each div you could use the `context` parameter of the AJAX call to provide the current div to the success handler:

```
$('div.foo').each(function(index, div) {
    $.ajax({
        url: item.ImagePath,
        dataType: 'script',
        context: div,
        success: function(data) {
            // here $(this) points to the div over which we were looping
            // when we triggered the AJAX request
            $(this).append($('<figure/>').append(result));
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have to append it to the supposed div, like this:

```
var sResultFigure = $('<figure></figure>').append(result);
$('#supposedDiv').append(sResultFigure);
```

Answer (score -1):

i assume your div's id is "holder".

```
var sResultFigure = $("<figure></figure>").append(result);
$('#holder').append(sResultFigure);
```